# What is HADOOP_CMD on Windows machine?

Tags: r, linux, windows, hadoop

I am learning about how to connect R to Hadoop.
Here is my environment setting:

**R**:

```
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
```

**Hadoop**:

```
running on another server
Linux Red Hat Enterprise
```

I have installed `rhdfs` and trying to load it but these error comes up:

```
> require(rhdfs)
Loading required package: rhdfs
Loading required package: rJava
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rhdfs’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rhdfs', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: Environment variable HADOOP_CMD must be set before loading package rhdfs
```

I searched around StackOverflow and found out I must set `HADOOP_CMD` env variable. But `HADOOP_CMD` env var is mostly set like '/path/to/bin/hadoop'.

Seems like this `HADOOP_CMD` refer to path that is in the same machine. What if my hadoop is on another machine? How do I specify the `HADOOP_CMD` variable?

Comment: I think you need to have at least a Hadoop client on the Windows machine.

Comment: You might want to try SparkR or sparklyr

Comment: @neilfws do you mind elaborating more?

Comment: @cricket_007: I try to look around for SparkR. Correct me if im wrong, but sparkR provides a 'layer' for R to interact with Spark language. What I am trying to do here is simpler than that. I want to connect to Hadoop and read csv files.

Comment: Spark isn't a language, it's an execution layer. And it provides methods to read csv data into dataframes

Comment: And to elaborate the first comment - You probably  need to download the Hadoop client commands (which additionally require installing Java)

Comment: @cricket_007 is there any website or tutorial I can follow? I am currently checking this website for sparkR: https://www.r-bloggers.com/installing-and-starting-sparkr-locally-on-windows-os-and-rstudio-2/. I don't see any connection to the Hadoop installed on Linux. Is the structure should be this: `Windows R -> sparkR -> Windows Hadoop Client -> Linux Hadoop`?

Comment: SparkR communicates with Hadoop via Scala / JVM, not native C

Comment: Also, Spark has its own website... Reading anything before version 2 of Spark is quite old

Comment: I am not familiar with rhdfs. But an environment variable is by definition specific to the local machine. If it's asking for HADOOP_CMD I assume at least some components of Hadoop are required locally to communicate with the server machine.